# Whatsapp Click to Chat sending an image instead of text

Tags: html, whatsapp

I want to send an image via the Whatsapp Click to Chat URL. Sending Text is easy.

https://wa.me/?text=LoremIpsum

When I click this link, it opens WhatsApp, and I can select which contact I want to send the message.

Now my question is, if its possible to also send an image through this URL. (maybe with an ?media=https://cdn.example.com/image.jpg parameter). The goal is to send an email to customers and let them click on a link so they can send an image from us to their friends.

Do I need WhatsApp Business for this? Or isn't it possible?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/media/

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. I know that there is an whatsapp business api. But I asked if there is a possibility to give the user an URL where he clicks on and then he selects a reciever ad than an image will be sended to him.

Comment: You should upload the file before sending it to the receiver. Why don't you read that from there docs? Create a custom application as per the documentation and give the custom URL to the user. From your custom application send your images through `POST` request as per WhatsApp api.

Comment: Well, we all are looking for exactly that but that is not something which is yet available and nor do I think it's going to be available.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70169236/add-file-in-whatsapp-desktop-chat-from-winform-c-sharp/70180397#70180397

Comment: @SumeshTG The whatsapp message has to go from UserX to UserY, not from businessPhoneNumber to UserY. The whatsapp business API does not provide a way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible with uri, but you can use Intents on android or use Navigator.share() method on webpages using javascript:

Android Intent: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

Web Share: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share

There are similar ways for other operating systems such as iOS, Windows, ...

Comment: The share option is useful to trigger a phone's share feature but it won't link you to whatsapp directly.

Comment: @Sarfaraaz On android, you can pass whatsapp package name to share on whatsapp directly. see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setPackage(java.lang.String)

Comment: Indeed. my comment was related to the navigator.share option