# Add file in WhatsApp Desktop chat from WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How's it going? I wanted to see if it is possible to attach a file from a `WinForms` application in `C#` and send it to **WhatsApp Desktop**. To start the **WhatsApp Desktop** application I use the following:

```
var process = $"whatsapp://send?phone={numero}&text={text}";
Process.Start(process);
```

With that, I get **WhatsApp Desktop** to open with a default text and a number entered by the user. Now, I would like to know if it is possible to attach a file **(image / pdf)** to that. I have tried the following:

> I create an `OpenDialog` from which I select the file and get its path, I put it in a `TextBox`.

Then, to the process I say the following:

```
string pathFile = txtRuta.Text;
var process = $"whatsapp://send?phone={numero}&text={text}&attachment={pathFile}";
Process.Start(process);
```

This starts the **WhatsApp Desktop** but it only shows me the text and the number where it will be sent. Is there any way to attach a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From knowledge-wise, it is not viable as it only supports string,

Please use the image URL instead.

Besides, you may also use the website URL. Often Web **Scraper** carries images preview of the website to Whatsapp so users will see the snapshot of the website.

Answer (score 0):

string v = $"https://wa.me/{textno.Text}?text={textmessae.Text}?attachment={ba}";
//ba is var wich contain the attached pic
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(v);`

Comment: what's ba? 'cause idk what is that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).